# Github Fine Grained PAT: remote: Write access to repository not granted

Tags: github

I'm trying to use Fine Grained Personal Access Tokens (PAT) as this seems to the recommended approach but running into difficulties. Steps I have followed are:

1. Configured organizational access to allow users to access reports based on PAT
2. Created a Fine grained PAT in my user account (initially keeping to default settings) and made the organiztion the resource owner
3. Confirmed that the organziation settings shows the new token as active
4. Tried to then do a git clone from cli git clone `https://github.com/XXXXX`
   where I get asked to select an authentication method, so I choose option 3. Personal Access token

This then results in the error:

```
remote: Write access to repository not granted.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/XXX.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I have tried going back and playing around with changing various permissions to ReadWrite and still no luck.

I then tried googling and YouTubing the problem, but from what I can gather no one really knows what all the different fine grained permissions do (YouTubers just gloss over it). And the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens?apiVersion=2022-11-28) on this is unintelligible.

Can someone provide a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to clone a repository with a fine-grained token the account must first be granted the write role as a member of that repository through the repository settings.

Then you can create a fine-grained PAT with read-only contents scope to allow cloning of a repository and prevent writing.

This is bizarre from GitHub, their permissions model is a complete wreck at the moment.